# Eclipse Plug-in: Accsessing and executing Java files in the workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is it possible to search the the workspace for specific *.java file and execute it from within plug-in (view)?

public class TestMessage {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    switch (args[0]) {
    case "1":
        System.out.println("The Argument 1 has been sent.");
        break;
    case "2":
        System.out.println("The Argument 2 has been sent.");
        break;
    case "3":
        System.out.println("The Argument 3 has been sent.");
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

Let's for example say, I have the above code and want to tirgger it from within a view....

Comment: You mean you're writing a plugin and want to search a file from it?

Comment: Not necessarily "searching" it as I know it is there. It is more about triggering a compile and run of a certain project with some args[]

Comment: Yes, it is all possible, it is also complicated. Start by reading the 'Program debug and launch support' section of 'Platform Plug-in Developer Guide' in the Eclipse help.